# Error while installing Ionic with node v5.0.0 and npm v3.3.6

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code

I have installed nodejs version 5.0.0 and npm 3.3.6 on my MacBook pro. Every time i try to install ionic i get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
```

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the Cordova API CLI requirements on OSX. i found out that i need the have all iOS SDK tools which is part of XCode installation.

Cordova CLI requirements for OSX:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/ios/index.html

So this is the steps to get Ionic up and running on OSX ElCapitan 10.11.1 and to fix the issue i had earlier:

1) Download and then Install XCode on your OSX.

2) Run the following command in your terminal:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova ionic
```

3) You will be able to install both Cordova and Ionic on your machine with no errors as it was showing earlier.

4) Try to create a project to validate everything is good to go in the terminal window:

```
ionic start mostafaApp1 tabs
```

You will find that the project has been created successfully.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use to have the exact same error.

In the Installation Guide from ionic (http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/) explains that you need a Node.js version 6 or greater to install ionic.

I fixed it by upgrading my Node.js to the current version "v6.8.0", and then my installation from ionic work without errors! :)

You can download the latest version from Node.js from the official website: "https://nodejs.org/en/"